Concatenating JSONPath with CDK variable
Trying to concatenate a string from JSONPath on a Step Function with a variable in CDK (like region or stack name). Is this possible to do?
Example I've tried and failed on so far:
let stackName = "test-stack-name";

new Pass(this, "Test Concatenation", {
      parameters: {
          "newString.$": `States.format('{}', $.validInputString, ${stackName})`
      },
    });

This isn't valid JSONPath but wondering is there a way to combine the two in Step Functions?

It looks like your syntax is close, but a bit off. I'm not 100% clear on the CDK translation here, but the value you provided seems to have two mistakes I can see. First, Format needs to be capitalized (e.g., States.Format). And you've provided two variables for replacement but only one placeholder in the template string. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-generic
